# A convergence result for functions in L^2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $f$ and $g$ be functions in $L^2$ [0,1]. 
Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere.

If $|f_n(x)| \leq |x|^{-1/3}$ prove that :

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)g(x) = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)$.

To me this looks very much like monotone convergence, but the existence of $g$ and the fact that the sequence may not be monotonic causes problems for me

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz and the pointwise bound $|f_{n}(x)||g(x)|\leq|x|^{-1/3}|g(x)|$ may be useful.

Comment: Adding to Sargera's comment, dominated convergence should get you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Define $h_n(x):=|f_n(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)|$. Since $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, we have $h_n\to 0$ almost everywhere. We also have $|f(x)|\leqslant x^{-1/3}$, hence 
$$|h_n(x)|\leqslant 2x^{-1/3}|g(x)|\leqslant x^{-2/3}+g(x)^2.$$
The function is the RHS is integrable, hence dominated convergence theorem applies.